# API Management - the same policy created for every operation

Tags: azure-api-management

When I add an API using the Function App option. All the functions are imported as operations and every operation has the same backend policy:

```
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-backend-service id="apim-generated-policy" backend-id="myfunctionapp" />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

I have a lot of these operations and all of them have the same policy.  There is a way to create a shared policy for all operations. So it would seem better to create one shared policy instead of policy for each operation.

Is there a way,  during the "add API" step,  to specify a shared policy for all operations and not have these policies on each operation? I couldn't find a way (at least not in Azure UI). Is there another way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **apply the policy to all operations**, select `All operations`.

Select the `</> (code editor)` icon in the Inbound processing section.

[image]

And then paste the desired policy code into one of the appropriate blocks.

```
<policies>    
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-backend-service id="apim-generated-policy" backend-id="myfunctionapp" />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

For more details you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/set-edit-policies#set-or-edit-a-policy).

Comment: That is correct, the policy can be applied for all operations. However, during the 'add API' process, the same policy gets applied to each individual operation (and I have about 100 of them). The 'add API' step should be smart enough to figure out that since all operations are coming from the same function app, the policy can be shared by all operations and does not need to be applied to each operation individually.

Comment: This is how we decided to import function app. It was driven by assumption that many customers would import multiple function apps into same API combining them at APIM level. And this is easier to do when function app specific policies are placed at operation level. If you're using only single function app in your API, indeed placing set-backend-policy would be easier at API level.

Comment: @vitaliy-kurokhtin that makes sense. Is there a way to disable this behavior so that these policies are not created during the 'add api' operation?  If not, is there a way to remove all the policies that are applied at the operation level?

Comment: I have the same problem, but this solution didn't work.  If I go to All Operations and paste in the correct inbound policy, it doesn't update the 72 operations that were automatically imported by the function app.  Should it bulk update the existing policies?  Thanks!